# New Root Category Not Display At FrontEnd

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I Have Created New Root Category As Name "New Store2"
And its also have subcategory As Name "laptops".

But It was not displays in front end.

[image]

[image: enter code here]

[image]

Comment: Check you display setting, Is Anchor must be Yes then it will show in front menu.

Comment: Is Anchor is "Yes"

Comment: Also it must be assign that new store as root category.

Comment: Name  : My Store2, 
Root Category : My Store2, 
Default Store View : mystore2

Comment: u can see second image

Comment: The third image, are you running on the second website ( My Store 2)?

Answer (score 1):

There are not any issue with your store but you need to run **mystore2**.

You have created **mystore2** and with root category, it is done.

Problem is that you are run **default** store on front side, you need to run **mastore2** then it will work for you.

Let me know if you have any query from above.